# Copy resources from one module to another by maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven managed project with some modules. One common parent module and some children. One children module contains resources directory. Second children module packages all related modules to a jar file. It's using assembly plugin in for this.

Question: **How can I copy the resources directory from first module to a directory in the second (packaging) module?**
I found `maven-dependency-plugin`, but still do not understand how to configure it.
Below is an example of my packaging module that creates jar from other modules, but without copying resources:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.rm</groupId>
    <artifactId>rm-core-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../rm-core-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
<artifactId>rm-app-package</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>rm-app-package</name>
<description>rm-app-package</description>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rm</groupId>
        <artifactId>rm-core-app</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>rm.core.app.RMCore</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>


            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> 
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have the jar it already contains the resources cause they have been packaged into the jar?